# To get a link to a specific email of a specific user in Gmail

Tags: hyperlink, gmail

With reference of [Obtain a link to a specific email in GMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780976/obtain-a-link-to-a-specific-email-in-gmail), I understand how to get a link to a specific email in Gmail with a thread id obtained from gmail API.

However, when there are multiple users login in chrome, https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/abc123def456 will always direct to the mailbox of user 1 but the thread id is actually from user 2. Therefore, the email can never be reached.

How can I determine which users' mailbox I am looking for with a thread id or other information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  in the URL indicates that it's for user #1, so if you want it to open for user #2, simply change the U/0 to U/1.

Keep in mind that the number is only based for that browser, and logged in users at the time, if you log out of one, every user in that browser gets logged out, and the u/# get's reset.

Cheers.