# Getting a direct link to an email

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap

I am making an app where the user can search through his/her email, using certain keywords, made with python and imap lib, but I cant figure how to open the mail the user want in the web browser, considering the user has already logged in. Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks.

EDIT: What Iam looking for is a way to get the link of the email(Gmail to be specific), that imap has "parsed"

Comment: It's not clear to me where you want to open the email? A specfic email-service? Could you clarify that, please?

Comment: gmail is what iam looking for, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain a link to a specific email in GMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780976/obtain-a-link-to-a-specific-email-in-gmail)

Comment: the thing is this will work if the message id (the thing that comes when the show original option is selected., but what i have is the uid (an int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/rfc822msgid: <MESSAGE_ID>')
```

The Message Id is located within the Email headers.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48014199/

Comment: this might work if have the link, the main problem is that iam not able to get the link from the email that imap has parsed.

Comment: I have found a partial solution by using the Message ID and using Gmail's search functionality to get that specific thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780976/obtain-a-link-to-a-specific-email-in-gmail

Comment: at last found a way to get the message id, thank you for the quick response,  I forgot look into the message headers that imap lib returns, thanks for mentioning it.