# Get gmail message hyperlink using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to get the Url of Gmail messages and store them into a Google Sheet. I'm doing this because the sheet will serve as a dashboard and I want to be able to link to specific messages which can be quickly opened by clicking the message hyperlink.

Gmail message urls will start with something like "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#inbox/" for messages in the 'inbox' followed by a string of around 70 characters representing a message ID such as "ZhatKJWQfkVxNWLWSctJlTPzJAjLTGmHOFwlqPWVTvjkwVgsnhBsfmJrrvjRDAHfKozQnYn".

As far as I can tell there is no way to get the full url from the [GMail Message class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message).  However you can retrieve the message id using getId().

So my approach was to retrieve the ID, append it to the inbox prefix ("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#inbox/") and that should create the link as follows:

```
for (var x = messageThread.length-1; x>=0; x--) {
for (var y = 0; y< numMessagesInThread; y++) {
var message = messageThread[x].getMessages()[y];
var messageId = message.getId();
var messageUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#inbox/" + messageId;
...
```

The problem is it turns out getId() doesn't return the 70 character Id in the original Url of the message but rather a 16 character Id such as "2487g294ie3f3x8z".  Needless to say when used in the URL it doesn't work.
I'm stuck at this point and have been searching for a way to do this, if anyone has ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing your url with `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox`. Let me know if that works for you, it does for me.

Comment: I tired that and it works perfectly!!  Thanks Dmirty!!  I'm trying to do the same thing now for a message in the Draft  using "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts/ + id" but it doesn't work.  It takes me to the Draft folder but not the specific message.  When I open the message the full Url is "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=" followed by the id so I also tried that and does the same thing takes me to the folder. Do you know why this is isnt working like the inbox?

Comment: What if you keep `#inbox` ?

Comment: No it doesn't work keeping #inbox.  However I noticed something strange... using the link "mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts/ + id" takes you to the draft folder and displays the draft folder url "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts".  Then if you simply add "/+id" paste it into the browser at the end of that link hit enter it opens the draft message!  I have no idea why it doesn't work when you use the full link the first time, but works this way.  Perhaps a workaround can be done to emulate this with appscript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain a link to a specific email in GMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780976/obtain-a-link-to-a-specific-email-in-gmail)

Comment: For someone who signed in with multiple gmail, the url can be modified like `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/username@gmail.com/#inbox`