# Can I create a Gmail link (a URL) that I can copy and paste into goggle sheets, which I can later click on to open up in my email program (gmail)?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

I use Gmail as my email (within Google Workspace), but I don't want to use it to manage my tasks, we clear out our inboxes every day and add any jobs to our workflow in google sheets. A lot of our tasks start out as emails and I often need to reference these emails.

Is there a script or another clever way to create a link (a URL) that I can copy and paste into google Sheets, that we can later click on that will open the email in Gmail? Is this possible at all?

Note I use cloud HQ to create a PDF copy but it's cumbersome and I would really like to write my own script - I just don't know where to start, any suggestions is really appreciated.

Comment: Looking at your post, you want to obtain the `URL` of every email that contains your tasks and place them on your sheet. Is this correct? If I'm right, have you research some similar posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358087/get-gmail-message-hyperlink-using-apps-script) as a starting point? Also kindly check [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Kind of, I want to build an in-Gmail app that easily copies the email URL that can be then pasted into google sheets which we can access now.  Thanks for your help though - you have actually helped me a lot - I will keep working on my skills asking questions as well.