# How to Open a Gmail Thread in the Mobile App?

Tags: android, gmail

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780976/obtain-a-link-to-a-specific-email-in-gmail) explains how to obtain a link to a particular Gmail thread. The proper domain to use is **mail.google.com** and this works perfectly on my desktop Chrome browser. However, when I open this link on my Android phone, it opens it in the Chrome browser rather than the Gmail app, and also does not open the particular thread and simply displays my inbox.

On my phone, I opened **Settings** > **Apps & notifications** > **Advanced** > **Default apps** > **Opening links** > **Gmail** > **Supported links** and found that the domain **mail.google.com** is not supported for opening in the Gmail app. I cannot figure out if there is a way to add it to the list of supported links.

My question is why is the **mail.google.com** domain not supported (seems pretty stupid imo) and is there a way to add it so that I can open a link to a particular Gmail thread directly in the Gmail app?

Comment: How are you "opening the link"?  By clicking on it in a browser?  That will only ever open it in a browser.  Also, that set of links has to be declared by the company that wrote the gmail app.  There's no way to add to it.  Complain to Google if you think they should add that as a feature.

Comment: @GabeSechan - I'm opening the link from the description of an event in the Google Calendar app on my phone. I figured that there was no way to add to the list, but I thought I'd ask here in case there was a workaround. Thanks, I'm going to go whine at Google now.

Comment: That would require the app to claim to understand that URL.  Which you'd have a good argument for.  But unless you're trying to write a program that opens up google mail links, that makes this question off topic here.